# Laravel - Calculate percentage increase or decrease in earning from last 30 days

Tags: laravel, eloquent, percentage

I have an earnings table in the Laravel application. I am getting sum of last 30 days by this query

```
$dateFrom = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
$dateTo = Carbon::now();
$monthly = Transaction::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->sum('amount');
```

Now I want to calculate the increase or decrease in earnings from the last 30 days to the previous last 30 days.

I am attaching the screenshot. This is how I want to show the percentage stat
[Click here to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M02vj.png)

Comment: If there are any logs for your old values with respect to a new one's then you should be able to track the Transaction

Comment: By logs you means ledger?

Comment: yes so you can able to calculate 30 days transaction with old once how much revenue generated for the last 30 days

Answer (score 0):

It's an approach from me. You can calculate another way for getting the result.

```
$dateFrom = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
$dateTo = Carbon::now();
$monthly = Transaction::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])- 
>sum('amount');

$previousDateFrom = Carbon::now()->subDays(60);
$previousDateTo = Carbon::now()->subDays(31);
$previousMonthly = Transaction::whereBetween('created_at', [$dateFrom,$dateTo])->sum('amount');

if($previousMonthly < $monthly){
    if($previousMonthly >0){
        $percent_from = $monthly - $previousMonthly;
        $percent = $percent_from / $previousMonthly * 100; //increase percent
    }else{
        $percent = 100; //increase percent
    }
}else{
    $percent_from = $previousMonthly -$monthly;
    $percent = $percent_from / $previousMonthly * 100; //decrease percent
}
```

Comment: If $previousMonthly value will be 0 due to no earning of previous last 30 days then error invokes "Division by zero"

Comment: Here, you can check the previous value is 0 or not. Answer edited.